# Allign button to the left in Kivy

Tags: python, button, kivy

I need to make a couple of buttons to appear to the right of a current `GridLayout` when certain actions are performed.

I've tried a `FloatLayout` with the whole screen, but I can't get it to go to the left with a relative position (since I will be working with more than one screen resolution).
I don't have code, but I have to do it from the `.py` because it follows a certain logic to appear.
I've tried this in the .kv:

```
    FloatLayout:
    Button:
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
        pos: root.width, root.height / 2
    GridLayout:
```

changing the pos to `pos_hint` and `halign: 'right'` but has't worked either

in the .py code i've tried to add it to the `on_touch_down` method so a Button appears every time like `boton = Button(text='caca', pos=self.width - root.x, root.height / 2)`
 but it doesn't either

Any help is welcome!

Comment: Please post some code of what you have tried?

Comment: @toto_tico I added the code I've tried, I'm sorry i'm still new to this and still don't know well how to ask questions correctly

Comment: those coordinates would be sending the button out of the screen. By code, I meant a full non-working example that we can replicate the exact problem and it is easier for the community to help. Other than that we have to simply guess the context.

Answer (score 0):

Your math calculations are incorrect, you need to subtract the width of the button to the `x` position, and half the height of it to the `y` position.

```
pos: root.width-self.width, root.height / 2 - self.height / 2
```

Here is a full working example.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<Base>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
            pos: root.width-self.width, root.height / 2 - self.height / 2
            text: 'hola'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: 'A'
        Label:
            text: 'B'
''')    

class Base(FloatLayout):
    pass

class BaseApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Base()

BaseApp().run()
```

This is, however easier to achieve with `pos_hint`:

```
pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'center_y': .5}
```

So, like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string('''
<Base>:
    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.2
            pos_hint: {'right': 1, 'center_y': .5}
            text: 'hola'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: 'A'
        Label:
            text: 'B'
''')    

class Base(FloatLayout):
    pass

class BaseApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Base()

BaseApp().run()
```